# Set up custom time to allow NSLocalNotif xcode

Tags: xcode

See sample code as follows - unable to use custom time here.  Why is this not possible giving a result:

```
NSDate *dt1 = [NSDate date]; //2018-07-26 08:31:22 +0000

NSString *datestr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];//2018-07-26 10:42:09 +0001

NSString *cutstring = 09:00 PM;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create date with NSDateComponents where you can set year, month, hour, minute etc.  [Refer https://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/](https://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/)

Extracting Components From Dates
NSDateComponents can be initialized and manipulated manually, but most often, they’re extracted from a specified date, using NSCalendar -components:fromDate::
Swift
Objective-C

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let date = NSDate()
let components = calendar.components([.Month, .Day], fromDate: date)
```

The components parameter is a bitmask of the date component values to retrieve, with many to choose from:
Swift
Objective-C

```
NSCalendarUnit.Era
NSCalendarUnit.Year
NSCalendarUnit.Month
NSCalendarUnit.Day
NSCalendarUnit.Hour
NSCalendarUnit.Minute
NSCalendarUnit.Second
NSCalendarUnit.Weekday
NSCalendarUnit.WeekdayOrdinal
NSCalendarUnit.Quarter
NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth
NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
NSCalendarUnit.YearForWeekOfYear
NSCalendarUnit.Calendar
NSCalendarUnit.TimeZone
```

Since it would be expensive to compute all of the possible values, specify only the components that will be used in subsequent calculations (joining with |, the bitwise OR operator).